# Postgresql : Count columns whose value starting with the value of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I count rows where a column value starts with a another column value ?

For example, I have table **products** shown below

```
---------------------------
id  code    abbreviation
---------------------------
1   AA01    AA
2   AB02    AB
3   AA03    AA
4   AA04    AB
---------------------------
```

I want to get the count of products whose code starts with abbreviation. A query like this

```
select count(*) from products where code ilike abbreviation+'%'
```

I am using postgresql 9.5.3

Comment: Are the abbreviations in fixed size?

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz No, abbreviations can be of any length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string concatenation operator in postgresql is: `||`

```
select count(*) from products where code like abbreviation || '%';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
select count(*) from products where code like '%'+abbreviation+'%'
```

But i am not sure why do you need this type of query.